# get the sum of related items that contained in one group the returned on condition

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, database-partitioning

this is related to another question [get first record in group by result base on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287689/get-first-record-in-group-by-result-base-on-condition/47287744#47287744)
to make it clear, I'll start from the beginning
this is my database structure create database testGroupfirst; go

```
use testGroupfirst;
go

create table testTbl (

id int primary key identity,name nvarchar(50) ,year int ,degree int , place  nvarchar(50)

)

insert into testTbl values ('jack',2015,50,'giza')
insert into testTbl values ('jack',2016,500,'cai')
insert into testTbl values ('jack',2017,660,'alex')
insert into testTbl values ('jack',2018,666,'giza')
insert into testTbl values ('jack',2011,50,'alex')
insert into testTbl values ('rami',2015,5054,'giza')
insert into testTbl values ('rami',2016,1500,'cai')
insert into testTbl values ('rami',2017,66220,'giza')
insert into testTbl values ('rami',2018,6656,'alex')
insert into testTbl values ('rami',2011,540,'cai')
insert into testTbl values ('jack',2010,50,'cai')
select * from testTbl
```

this is the result till now
[image]

to get the latest 2 orders, etc  from a group by this could be solved by this code

```
SELECT name, year, degree, place
FROM 
(SELECT name,degree, year,  place,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY degree desc) rn
     FROM testTbl   
) t    
WHERE rn in(1,2,3);

--another way
select t.* 
from testTbl t
    cross apply (select top 2 id from testTbl t2 where t2.name = t.name order by degree desc) r
where t.id = r.id
```

i need to get aggregate function like sum to get the sum of all related items in one group 
i make a code like this

```
select t.*, sum (t.degree) as sumtest 
from testTbl t  
    cross apply (select top 2 id ,degree  , sum (degree) as sumtest from testTbl t2 where t2.place = t.place group by id,degree order by degree  ) r
where t.id = r.id group by t.id,t.name,t.place,t.year,t.degree
```

but it didn't work like I thought as I need to make aggregate value not scalar for every item itself , i need to get the sum of all items in one group 
what i need to get is what shown in this pic 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another window function:

```
    SELECT name, year, degree, place, sum(degree) over (partition by name) as [sum]
    FROM 
    (SELECT name,degree, year,  place,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY degree desc) rn
         FROM #testTbl   
    ) t  
    WHERE rn in(1,2,3);
```

Comment: this is worked fine , thanks
another way using cross apply
select t.* ,sum(degree) over (partition by name) as [sum]
from testTbl t
    cross apply (select top 3 id from testTbl where name = t.name order by year) r
where t.id = r.id

Answer (score 0):

This could be one approach

```
  select 
  name,
  SUM(degree) sumtest 
  into #test
  from testTbl 
  group by name

  select b.*, a.sumtest from #test a 
  join
  testTbl b on b.name = a.name
```